# Windows Phone 7 WebBrowser element

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a next problem, i have JSON articles. Article text is formatted as HTML, thats why i have WebBrowser element on the form, and i do this:

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString("<p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'>" + (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage.Title + "</p><br/>" + (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage.Text);
```

But in Windows Phone 7 the displayed info is broken - doesn't display such simbols as: ā,ī etc...

I have tried to do this:

Adding charset -had no effect...

```
ArticleContent.NavigateToString("<!DOCTYPE><html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' /></head><body><p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'>" + (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage.Title + "</p><br/>" + (App.Current as App).ToArticlePage.Text + "</body></html>");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've tried: `WebBrowser.NavigateToString("<p style='font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;'> ā,ī e</p><br/> ā,ī e")`, and it seems to work fine. Maybe the problem is elsewhere. Have you tried displaying your string in a messagebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem recently. You need to fix the encoding of the extended ascii characters like this:

```
    string ConvertExtendedASCII(string HTML)
    {
        string retVal = "";
        char[] s = HTML.ToCharArray();

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(c) > 127)
                retVal += "&#" + Convert.ToInt32(c) + ";";
            else
                retVal += c;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```